# Specifying eulervm as mathfont in fontspec

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fontspec

Is it possible at all to set the Euler Virtual Math fonts (or other post script math fonts) in fontspec using `\setmathrm`. I want to this, rather than just loading the package, because I would like to use the `ScaleLowerCase` Option of fontspec. I tried loading eulervm in fontspec with various settings, but without any success.

Comment: `\setmathfont{Neo Euler}`

Comment: the option is also `Scale=MatchLowercase` which you would specify as `\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Neo Euler}`

Comment: I know that I can use Neo Euler, but I meant the post script font provided by the eulervm package.

Comment: `\usepackage{eulervm}` _before_ loading `fontspec`

Comment: As I said in my question, I ask if it is *in principle* possible to load post script math fonts with fontspec, because I want to use the MatchLowercase option. I know of unicode math, but the support is still experimental.

Comment: @Jörg As far as I understand it, you are generally asking whether it is possible to scale math fonts (possibly using `fontspec`) to match other fonts in the document.  Is that correct?

Comment: The goal is to scale a postscript math-font to the x-height of the open type main font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `fontspec` cannot be used to load 'traditional' virtual fonts. The only way to proceed is to first load the virtual font package and then use `fontspec` for loading the OpenType font(s) you want to use.