# Old Style Fonts not applied to whole document

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, oldstylenums

The old style font is not applied to the whole document. Whats the issue there?
The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\begin{document}
92\si{\percent}\par
$84^\star$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is because you have to specify the math font separately. (Like `\setmathfont{...}`, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47628/specifying-eulervm-as-mathfont-in-fontspec. In the extreme case you can do `$\text{84}^\star$` (needs `amsmath`).

Comment: IMO, the main problem here is not that the numbers are lining in “math mode” but the different font you use for the numbers in math mode. There is a package which offers math support for Libertine: `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`.

Comment: there are some relevant comments on the difference in use of lining vs. old-style numerals in the tugboat article by knuth about typesetting the book *concrete mathematics*.  there's a link to the article in the answer to question 22244.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mathematical writing, it is not common to use oldstyle (aka "text-style") numerals, whether or not oldstyle numerals are used in ordinary text. I believe lining-style numerals are preferred for math-mode material for two reasons. First, using text-style figures (some of which have descenders, and some of which have ascenders) in superscript and subscript positions -- which happens rather a lot in math, doesn't it? -- can quickly confuse the reader. Second, text-style figures are usually (but not necessarily) proportionally spaced -- i.e., a `1` takes up less space than a `6` -- and are therefore not well suited for displaying numbers in tabular contexts; in contrast, lining-style figures are generally (but, again not necessarily) fixed-spaced and therefore much better suited for tabular material.

The `libertine` package is not the only package that does not use oldstyle numerals in math mode even though the `osf` option is specified. For instance, loading the `cfr-lm` package (which is based on the Latin Modern font families) with the option `rm=oldstyle` won't enable the use of oldstyle numerals in math. Similarly, beginning with version 1.23 of the `newtx` and `newpx` packages (which are based on the Times Roman and Palatino font families, respectively), setting the option `osf` only affects numerals in text mode but not those in math mode.

Turning to the issue of how one might (note: I'm not saying *should") use oldstyle numerals together with macros of the `siunitx` package. From section 5.2 of the user manual of the `siunitx` package:

> The siunitx package controls the font used to print output independently of the surrounding material. The standard method is to ignore the surroundings entirely, and to
>   use the current body fonts.

You can override this setting by setting the package's option `detect-mode` (note again that I don't *recommend* you do so):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\begin{document}
\SI{84}{\kilogram}

\num{36.1}\%

\sisetup{detect-mode}

\SI{84}{kilogram}

\num{36.1}\%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP need not use math mode. He should use `\tnote` actually, but he is caught with $^{\star}. See his previous question about `threeparttable.` May be this is better advised to him.

Comment: @HarishKumar - Thanks for providing this additional pointer. I agree with you that the OP probably shouldn't be using math mode for simple numbers; much better to use the `\tnote` device to generate table notes in a `threeparttable` environment.